# Boilerplate .htaccess mod_deflate not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, html5boilerplate

I just uploaded site to the web host (it is using CPanel) and I am using **Boilerplate** .htaccess file (unchanged) - so the **mod_deflate** should be working, but it not (I checked this at http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ (address is [okcpirot.rs](http://okcpirot.rs)) ).
I am new to this things - is there something I need to turn on in CPanel in order for this to work or it is supposed to work automatically?

Code for **mod_deflate**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

  # Force deflate for mangled headers developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because mod_deflate.c isn't installed or it is disabled. As you can see, the script first checks if mod_deflate.c is installed (`<IfModule mod_deflate.c>`). That's probably not the case.

Your best bet is to ask your hostingprovider if they can enable it.